# How did the Hanja-rooted terms for sports such as '축구','야구', '농구' come into being?

Tags: etymology, word-origin

As football, baseball, and basketball are all relatively modern things, I might have expected their Korean terms to be transliterations of foreign terms (in the same way that the words 'taxi', 'computer', 'coffee', and so on have come into Korean). I find it intriguing that the common terms for these sports are the Hanja-rooted words '축구','야구', and '농구'.

How did these terms enter the Korean language?

Comment: I'm asking about these terms together as I expect there might be some similarities in the explanations - but happy to split into separate questions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67995/discussion-on-question-by-topo-morto-how-did-the-hanja-rooted-terms-for-sports-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're [Wasei-Kango](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wasei-kango) words imported from Japan during the Japanese colonial occupation of Korea:

- **蹴球** - Literally **kick-ball** (not **football**, which would be **足球/족구**), from Japanese **蹴球/しゅうきゅう**
- **野球** - Literally **field-ball**, from Japanese **野球/やきゅう**
- **籠球** - Literally **basket-ball**, from Japanese **籠球/ろうきゅう**

Interestingly, Japanese only retains the Kanji word 野球 out of the three; the other two have become English transliterations of *soccer* and *basketball*.

Answer (score 4):

football: foot is 축 in Hanja.
          and ball is 구in hanja.
baseball:baseball is a ball played in field. and field is 야 in hanja.
         and ball is 구in hanja.
basketball:basket is similar to box and box is 농 in hanja.
         and ball is 구in hanja.
Many Japanese, Korean, Chinese(especially Japanese) changed foreign words to Hanja words at 18th~19th century.